# Simple output loop fails in Visual Studio Code terminal when compiled with cl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, output, cl

Consider the simple program, in file a.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It works fine when I run it in the Visual Studio Code (Powershell) terminal after compiling it on Windows with Cygwin g++, like so:

```
g++ a.cpp -o a.exe
```

However, I get strange and inconsistent behavior when I run it after compiling it with cl like so (in a separate program, the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017):

```
cl a.cpp
```

When run in the Visual Studio Code (Powershell) terminal after compiling it this way, it stops outputting numbers well before 9999. Furthermore, it stops outputting at a different point each run. Running the program from a .bat script to check the %errorlevel% indicates that the error code is 0, so it doesn't seem to be crashing during the loop.

This, on the other hand, works totally fine from the VSCode terminal when compiled with cl, outputting 9999 every time:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int j = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        j++;
    }
    std::cout << j << std::endl;
}
```

So it seems like code compiled with cl will just stop outputting data written to std::cout after a little while when run from the Visual Studio Code terminal. But why would that happen?

## Update

It works perfectly after compiling with cl when running from Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, or from Powershell, or from Command Prompt. It only has the strange behavior when (a) compiled with cl instead of g++ and (b) run from a Powershell terminal within VSCode.

Comment: nvcc isn't a compiler and it isn't compiling that code. It will just pass through to the visual C++ compiler.

Comment: Do you have a compatible version of Visual Studio installed?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have Visual Studios 2015 and 2017 installed.

Comment: is `nvcc` using cygwin g++ or VS cl.exe?  You can figure that out with the ---`--verbose` option on `nvcc`.

Comment: @talonmies aha, that makes sense. I get the same behavior when I compile the program from the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 using cl. So this isn't really an nvcc issue at all. I'll update the tags and the question.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for the tip. It's using cl.exe. And as I pointed out in my other comment to talonmies, it seems like the problem occurs when using that compiler in general (since as he helpfully points out, nvcc isn't a compiler).

Comment: Hello. I wonder if this is at all related to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36787.

Comment: @GabrielL. Good catch. Commented the additional information, that it seems to be compiler dependent, on that issue. I'd consider this the answer if you want to rewrite it as such.